# How to change the height of only one specific row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a `UITableView` with content dynamic prototypes, whitch it displays name and surname in two different cells but this is hard cause there's a lot of space and I wish fix it by using simply one label string command like:

`namesurnamecell.textLabel?.text = "\(name!) \n \(surname!)"`

Unfortunately, the cell can't display the rest of the string.
So I tried to use this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    let namesuramecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "namesurnamecell", for: indexPath)
    namesurnamecell.contentView.frame.size.height = 100
}
```

And it obviously not worked, so I splitted this values in two cells for use another method, but it still not going:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
   if indexPath.section == 0
   {
       if indexPath.row == 1
       {
           return 5.0
       }
   }

   return 5.0
}
```

Comment: why did you think cell can't display rest of the String? Was it you don't want to or anything else? cause the label can show whole String when you set Lines property to 0.

Comment: If you r using autolayout provide correct constrains and use UITableViewAutomaticDimension then height  of the row is automatically      increase buy you have give number no.of line = 0 ,and line break mode = .wordwrap ,If your using auto resize or programmatically design you have to calculate height of the label you self .If you want code let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write this line in cellForRowAt method.

```
namesurnamecell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Then you do not need to manage heights. It will automatically manage heights.

Comment: Glad to help you :)